# imageline (PHP+gd) creates too long line

Tags: php, math, line, gd, complex-numbers

I'm trying to draw a line representing a complex number on a circle (base image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTUu5.png) starting from the centre of the circle and ending on a point on the circle. But here come the problems:
<strike>i have tried many formulas to find $x2 and $y2 but i always ended up with randomly positioned lines. What's the right formula to calculate the ending coordinates?</strike>

EDIT: thanks to Cleong i solved the positioning problem but the line is still too long, it goes out of the circle and even out of the image. As of now the formulas i use are:

```
$x2=$half+($radius*(cos(deg2rad($theta))));
$y2=$half-($radius*(sin(deg2rad($theta))));
```

Where $half is the centre of the circle (in pixels), $radius is the radius of the circle in pixels and $theta is the angle in radians.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The input to `sin()` and `cos()` needs to be in radian. Pass `$theta` to `deg2rad()` first.

Comment: Thank you @cleong, the trick worked like a charm. Now the line is too long but in the right position. Do i have to multiply the x2 for the radius of the circle or for the modulus of the number ($rho)?